# Is Robot Framework stateful or stateless?

Tags: python, ssh, robotframework

I believe it is stateless, but the specific situation is as follows:

I need to create a keyword library that will test a remote server by logging in via SSH, execute a CLI, and sending the CLI commands.  The issue is I have around 60k test cases that I'm trying to simulate, which send commands in different iterations at different times, so basically I need, at minimum, keywords to do the following:

1. connect via ssh and open the CLI
2. send a command via a preexisting CLI session
3. close the CLI and disconnect

I need these commands to store state, so that I can call keyword1 at the start of my test case and store the session for multiple calls to keyword2 at various times.  I also need to be able to store multiple independent sessions.

Is this kind of problem doable using Robot?

Comment: I've never used `robotframework` but I do know you could do this using `subprocess`. Let me know if you'd like to explore alternatives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To directly answer your question, it can be either. Libraries can have one of three scopes which control how long the library maintains its state. By using the GLOBAL scope, only once instance of the library will be created, and will remain for the life of the test execution. The other choices give you a fresh library instance for every test suite, or for every test case.

From the [robot framework user guide section on library scopes](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#test-library-scope), the supported scopes are:

**TEST CASE**: A new instance is created for every test case. A possible suite setup and suite teardown share yet another instance. This is the default.

**TEST SUITE**: 
A new instance is created for every test suite. The lowest-level test suites, created from test case files and containing test cases, have instances of their own, and higher-level suites all get their own instances for their possible setups and teardowns.

**GLOBAL**:
Only one instance is created during the whole test execution and it is shared by all test cases and test suites. Libraries created from modules are always global.

Comment: thanks.  but what if I need multiple instances of a library in  a single test case?

Comment: @ewok: why would you need multiple instances of a library?

Comment: because I need to store multiple ssh connections.  basically I need to be able to use the `Send Message` keyword in multiple contexts.  I might use it to send a message to CLI-a and then immediately use it to send a different message to CLI-b, but I need to be able to access these CLIs separately throughout the test case

Comment: @ewok: are you talking about the ssh library? You can open multiple connections with a single instance of the library

Comment: ok.  how do i distinguish between them when calling a keyword? [here](http://pastebin.com/qGnNY0U4) is an example of what I'm trying to do.  I need to open 2 CLI sessions and need to distinguish between them somehow when sending messages.

Comment: @ewok: that needs to be a separate question.

Comment: What do you mean? That was the original question.

Comment: @ewoc: the original question said you need to create a stateful library. Now you are asking how to use the ssh library to open more than one connection.